# How does prometheus rate works with grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

The rate function in grafana for example:- `rate(http_requests_total{job="api-server"}[5m])`  returns the per-second rate of HTTP requests as measured over the last 5 minutes.
How does this work with the time range that we set in grafana dashboard like 2h,4h, 24h etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are no interrelations between these two settings. For example, if `rate(http_requests_total{job="api-server"}[5m])` is your PromQL query, it yields a single value when you execute it at a specific point in time. If you have a Grafana dashboard with a 2h time range, then Grafana just repeatedly executes this query at a series of point in times during the past 2 hours, and displays you the result of each query as e.g. a graph.

For example, if the time range of your Grafana dashboard is 2h and the interval is set to 1 minute, then Grafana executes your query 120 times during the time span ranging the past 2 hours. The results of all these queries form a graph and that's what you see in your Grafana dashboard.

The interval with which Grafana executes the query is determined by the *Max data points* and *Min interval* settings in the *Query options* of your Grafana dashboard:

[image]

See the explanations about these settings in the [Grafana documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/queries/#query-options).

> Note: Grafana uses the [`query_range`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries) endpoint of the Prometheus API to repeatedly execute the query over the given time range.

Comment: So let's say I set the time range from 10:00AM to 11:00AM in grafana with min interval 15s. So in total it will execute 60*4=240 prom query which will result in 240 data points and based on that graph will be displayed.
So grafana will execute first query in 10:00AM and then 10:00:15AM, 10:00:30AM, 10:00:45AM , 10:01:00AM and so on.....
Is my understanding correct with this?

Comment: Yes, that's totally correct.

Comment: Thanks! Really great explanation

Comment: This is really good to know if you are looking to optimize Managed Prometheus costs on AWS which charges for queries. +1